# Мультикурсор Visual Studio 2022/2017. Как включить?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У меня вопрос как включить в Visual Studio (!!!не VS Code!!!) мультикурсор? Я пошарил и ничего не нашел. Может есть какая-нибудь <kbd>комбинация</kbd> как в ***IntelliJIdea***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зажимаешь <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> и кликаешь куда тебе надо вставить курсоры.
 Проеверил на Visual Studio 2022

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 3):

- Ctrl + Alt + Click - ставит дополнительный курсор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Alt+мышь - вытягивает курсор столбиком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

А все нашел (правда методом тыка). Для включения мультикурсора нужна комбинация 
 <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Щелчок мыши</kbd> + <kbd>Потянуть мышь вниз</kbd>. Но это работает только если нужен мультикурсор на нескольких строчек ***ПОДРЯД***, так же работает комбинация <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все же еще есть вопрос как делать этот курсор на нескольких строках не последовательных.